# How to move Websites built in SDL Tridion and hosted on a dedicated AWS infrastructure into a separate entity or infrastructure?

Tags: sdl-tridion, sdl-cloud

We currently have all our Tridion publications under one AWS infrastructure and now some of the sites needs to move to a different entity/company having their own cloud and everything. Is there a way to copy the publications to a separate infra. as an independent entity with minimal impact and effort?

I did some research on content porter but having large components it would take long. Also any suggestions on separate infrastructure would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of questions to your simple question but I do appreciate that using Content Porter (at least using the Content Porter GUI) may be very cumbersome. So, with that said - remember you can use the Import/Export services to remove GUI interaction ***if it suits the solution/processes etc.***

Thinking very generically have you looked at the possibility of standing up the different CM instances *wherever the need to go* from a single database backup. It sounds like you could then selectively delete the publications (and related content) that you don't need *for each site*.

Caveat - this is super-dooper-high-level.

***EDIT:*** In answer to the comment on 'shared infrastructure'...

It seemed that you intended to preclude a shared infrastructure with the statement "to move to a different entity/company having their own cloud and everything".

Maybe you can provide a tenanted system thus requiring only one SQL Server License but I'm not sure how you would best approach from the perspective of requiring either a multi-tenanted CM environment; if this is the path required then different CMs won't work but you're likely looking at different publications/Bllueprinting requirements.

It sounds like a fantastic challenge but not something to review in this forum (sounds more like a business/implementation *, in general,* challenge).

Comment: Database backup and delete unwanted pubs would be my favourite. Especially if the sites are more or less independent of each other.

Comment: I like the idea of standing up different CM instances, but would be concerned about the AWS part. Can you also share your thoughts on performance aspect and ease of maintenance for a shared infrastructure?